# i have create shortcode that work but not perfect coding

Tags: shortcode

I want to create a shortcode where content is displayed if user meta is equal to a value

It Works but it's code isn't perfect

how would you have done? How Can I improve it?

Example content display if firstname user is Jeff

```
[check-if-equal usermeta="firstname" uservalue="Jeff"] Yes [/check-if-equal]
```

This is the code handling the above shortcode

```
<?php
function func_check_if_equal( $atts, $content = null ) { 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { /* check if logged in */

    $user_meta = $atts['usermeta'];
    $user_value = $atts['uservalue'];



    /* get value from shortcode parameter */
    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); /* get user id */
    $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id ); /* get user meta */
    if ( $user_data->$user_meta == $user_value ) { /* if user meta is equal meta value */
        return $content; /* show content from shortcode */
    } else {
        return ''; /* meta field don't equal */ }
    } else {
        return ''; /* user is not logged in */
    }
}
}
add_shortcode( 'check-if-equal', 'func_check_if_equal' );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are 2 wrong things.

First of all, your shortcode itself is wrong.

You used

```
[check-if-equal usermeta="firstname" uservalue="Jeff"] Yes [/check-if-equal]
```

but there is nothing like `firstname` in Wordpress, It's `first_name`

So your shortcode should look like this,

```
[check-if-equal usermeta="first_name" uservalue="Jeff"] Yes [/check-if-equal]
```

Once that is done, rest looks cool I edited the question itself, for formatting syntax correctly. So it should look like this:

```
<?php
function func_check_if_equal( $atts, $content = null ) { 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { /* check if logged in */

    $user_meta = $atts['usermeta'];
    $user_value = $atts['uservalue'];


    /* get value from shortcode parameter */
    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); /* get user id */
    $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id ); /* get user meta */
    if ( $user_data->$user_meta == $user_value ) { /* if user meta is equal meta value */
        return $content; /* show content from shortcode */
    } else {
        return ''; /* meta field don't equal */ }
    } else {
        return ''; /* user is not logged in */
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'check-if-equal', 'func_check_if_equal' );
```

You asked me to Improve the code also, so there are 2 things which can be improved.

It should work perfectly, but there is one first thing u missed is that It can be that someone used the shortcode and types "jeff" instead of "Jeff" or may be they write "JEFF" instead of "Jeff". This can be problematic, as they type the same name, but still condition won't match, so below I have first of all made it work with all capital small variations, and then removed unnecessary else.

Secondly you unnecessarily cluttered the else statements, it could be done in simpler way. Both things corrected.

```
function func_check_if_equal( $atts, $content = null ) { 
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { /* check if logged in */

        $user_meta = $atts['usermeta'];
        $user_value = $atts['uservalue'];


        /* get value from shortcode parameter */
        $user_id = get_current_user_id(); /* get user id */
        $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id ); /* get user meta */
        if ( strtolower($user_data->$user_meta) == strtolower($user_value) ) { /* if user meta is equal meta value */
            return $content; /* show content from shortcode */
        }
    }
return '';
}
add_shortcode( 'check-if-equal', 'func_check_if_equal' );
```

Comment: Reason for downvote please?

Comment: I consider My answer, accurate, so please if you think there's anything wrong with my answer, then please inform me.

Comment: THX Aditya Agarwal

Comment: u are welcome buddy

Comment: I will try to improve to have multiple usermeta example [check-if-equal usermeta="first_name" uservalue="Jeff,Jenny"] Yes [/check-if-equal]

show content if first_name is Jeff or Jenny

Comment: Oh great, do u expect me to help you with that? or will u handle it?

Comment: I will try because I am a beginner but if you want to put your code it would be a pleasure to see

Comment: I can't do shortcode with multiple uservalue. How to do ? with explode ?

Comment: Yes explode the ',' shortcode attribute, and asign it to a variable, this will give u an array, then u can simply use foreach rest remains same

Answer (score 0):

You could clean up the code a bit, but nothing you did was that bad.

```php
function prfx_conditional_user_content( $attributes, $content = null ) {

    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $meta = $attributes['meta'];
        $value = $attributes['value'];
        $current_user_meta = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );

        if( $current_user_meta->$meta === $value ) {
            return $content;
        }
    }

    return '';

}

add_shortcode( 'conditional-content', 'prfx_conditional_user_content' );
```

Edit: As Aditya pointed out, `firstname` isn't a valid property. The correct one is `first_name`. [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/#public-properties) is a list of properties available to you by the WP User object.

Comment: U must have pointed out that he was using wrong meta in the shortcode html itself. His code probably wont even work

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal You're right—I assumed it was just a typo.

Comment: great that u corrected it

Comment: THX Jxxe ... yes tupo